# Changing background colour with jQuery. Reset to default

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a `<ul>`, in which I am using jQuery UI Sortable to allow the sorting of the contained `<li>`s.

The `<li>`s are styled with alternating background colours with :

```
.list-striped li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}
```

I am using the Sortable start and stop functions to create a nice transition when the `<li>` is dragged like so:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
        start: function(event, ui){
            $(ui.item).animate({
                'background-color': '#333333'
            }, 'fast');
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            $(ui.item).animate({
                'background-color': ''
            }, 'fast');
        }
    });
```

My issue now, is that when we clear the background colour, it doesn't revert to the previous background colour (or inherit the background colour it should from the CSS). Is what I am trying to achieve possible?

Comment: What you are doing is setting on the stop function the `background-color` to nothing. That doesn't revert the color, it sets it to nothing. you could use a variable to store the initial color before animating it to #333333 and then you have the value to animate it back.

Comment: .css("backgroundColor","") should remove the background color property in the style attribute; use your firebug to see what's happening to your li

Comment: have you tried setting it to "inherit" instead of the empty string?

Comment: if you aren't concerned with backward compatibility, use addClass and removeClass to add a highlight class with the background colour, and use a CSS3 transition for the animation.

Comment: You use `...:nth-child(odd)...` to achieve the zebra stripes in the first place, so you need to do something similar to restore zebra stripes on stop. As you want to animate, you will need to animate odds and event separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use jQuery to animate colors, use `CSS transitions` instead:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable();
```

CSS:

```
.list-striped li{
  width:200px;
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  padding:10px;
  transition: background 0.2s linear;
  -o-transition: background 0.2s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 0.2s linear;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.2s linear;
   cursor:pointer;
}
.list-striped li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #faa;
}
.list-striped li.ui-sortable-helper{
  background-color:#a55 !important;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgs7F/5/)

Comment: If you can insure that you don't need to support browsers that are not supporting CSS3

Comment: Well, CSS transition is suported in all modern browsers (except IE). You should NEVER avoid technologies just because IE doesn't support them... If you really care about IE you could simply include one of the many javascript libraries which make your website much more "IE-friendly"...

Comment: You shouldn't be so dogmatic on that point. Many organisations have a policy of not using any technology that is not supported by all the major browsers. If you want to adopt a different policy, that's up to you.

Comment: Well it's supported in IE >= 10. And as I said, if you want your webapp to really be cross-browser that's only including-one-file away.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. For some reason I had it in my head that CSS transitions didn't apply when adding/removing classes. I thought it was only on hover/active

Comment: I have simplified the code as it is unnecessary to add/remove another class, because the dragged item automatically gets `ui-sortable-helper` class

Answer (score 2):

YOu should store first the original value in another variable, let say `originalcolor`
so

```
var orginalcolor;
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
    start: function(event, ui){
        orginalcolor = $(ui.item).css('background-color'); //store the color
        $(ui.item).animate({
            'background-color': '#333333'
        }, 'fast');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui){
        $(ui.item).animate({
            'background-color': originalcolor
        }, 'fast');
    }
});
```

Comment: This is good... I ve' Tried your code here http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/QUxzA/, and it is working fine.

Comment: But there isn't just one original color. The lis are zebra striped.

Comment: this original color work also on zebra stripes, because it take currently dragging object background color as original background color

Comment: @A.K, either you or I has misunderstood the problem. I don't know who is right.

Comment: Yeah the idea behind this, was that every time that he moves an item it stores the value before moving it.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple, but wont animate

```
$(ui.item).removeAttr("style");
```